# Neural networks - Finding o/p from two distinct i/p patterns

Tags: neural-network

I have two distinct (unknown relationship) types of input patterns and I need to design a neural network where I would get an output based on both these patterns. However, I am unsure of how to design such a network.

I am a newbie in NN but I am trying to read as much as I can. In my problem as far as I can understand there are two input matrices of order say 6*1 and an o/p matrix of order 6*1. So how should I start with this? Is it ok to use backpropogation and a single hidden layer?

e.g.->

```
Input 1  Input 2  Output
 0.59       1       0.7 
 0.70       1       0.4
 0.75       1       0.5
 0.83       0       0.6
 0.91       0       0.8
 0.94       0       0.9
```

How do I decide the order of the weight matrix and the transfer function?

Please help. Any link pertaining to this will also do. Thanks.

Comment: in the example - is each line a sample on its own, or is that whole thing a single sample (and then for the training you'll have multiple sets of 6 lines each)?

Comment: @Ofri: whole thing is a single sample... Yes you have the right idea :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest thing to try is to concatenate the 2 input vectors. This way you'll have 1 input vector of length 12, and this becomes a "text-book" learning problem from R^{12} to R^{6}.
The downside of this, is that you lose the information about each 6 inputs coming from a different source, but by your description it doesn't sound like you know much about these sources. Anyways, if you have any special knowledge of the 2 sources, you can use some pre-processing (like subtracting the mean, or dividing by the standard deviation) on each of the sources, to make them more similar, but most learning algorithms should also work OK without it.

As for which algorithm to try, I think the cannonical order is: linear machines (perceptron), then SVM, then multi-layer-networks (trained with backprop). The reason is, the more powerful the machine you use, the better chances you have to fit the train set, but less chances to fit the "true" pattern (overfitting).